# How to make Jump link after load from controller in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

i have some question about how to create jump link after load from controller in codeigniter. i have some idea to combine jquery script after load from controller

here is what i already tried :

in index.php i create this code

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Create Jump Link Page <h1>
<Br>
......
<br>
<div id="bottom">bottom line</div>
<body>

<script>
  $(window).on('load', function() {
      var jumplink = "<?php echo $goto; ?>";
      var top = document.getElementById(jumplink).offsetTop;
      window.scrollTo(0, top);
    });
</script>
<html>
```

in controller file

```
public function index() { 
     $param['goto'] = "bottom";
     $this->load->view('admin/index', $param);
}
```

but it is not working. how do i can make link jump after load from controller.. is that possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Create Jump Link Page <h1>
<Br>
......
<br>
<div id="bottom">bottom line</div>
<body>

<script>
  $(window).on('load', function() {
      var jumplink = "<?php echo $goto; ?>";
      $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $('#'+jumplink).offset().top
     }, 1800);
    });
</script>
<html>
```